# openssl_sign() [function.openssl-sign]: Unknown signature algorithm in server

Tags: php, google-api

I am using google sheet api to access google sheet using php and all works fine in my localhost but when i have uploaded library to server and run the program it throws an exception`openssl_sign() [function.openssl-sign]: Unknown signature algorithm`.

Actually execution stops here in if condition and throws an exception.

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) 
{
   echo "<br> execution stops here <br>";
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
```

Exception:

```
[message:protected] => openssl_sign() [function.openssl-sign]: Unknown signature algorithm.
[file:protected] => /mywebsite/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Signer/P12.php
```